# a++ vs a = a + 1 which is useful in efficient memory programming and how?

Tags: c, programming-languages

This was my Interview question in HP. I answered a++ takes less instruction compared to a = a +1;

I want to know which is useful in efficient programming, and how both are different from each other..?

Hoping for quick and positive response..

Comment: This looks like a dupe/unanswerable question/bad interview technique.

Comment: What is "efficient programming"?

Comment: Both should be recognizable by any experienced C++ programmer. However, I read `a++` faster than `a = a + 1` which is the best argument I have.

Comment: a++ is fast why so i want the explanation how its efficient than a = a +1;

Comment: a++ (if I'm remember correctly) is an operation that modifies directly the variable (modifying directly bite) as a=a+1 requires the addition of a with another number. so if not optimized by your compiler it has to add 2 numbers bite by bite.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C, there would be no difference, if the compiler is smart.

In C++, it depends on what type `a` is, and whether the `++` operator is overloaded. To complicate matters even more, the `=` operator can be overloaded too, and `a = a + 1` might not be the same as `a++`. For even **more** complication, the `+` operator can also be overloaded, so an innocent looking piece of code such as `a = a + 1` might have drastic implications.

So, without some context, you simply cannot know.

Comment: There's no operator overloading in C (see tag).

Comment: @Vovanium: when I mentioned operator overloading, I mentioned C++. Nowhere did I say there's operator overloading in C. And when I answered this question, there was a C++ tag (see edit history).

Answer (score 7):

First of all, in C++ this will depend on type of `a`. Clearly `a` can be of class type and have those operators overloaded and without knowing the details it's impossible to decide which is more efficient.

That said, both in C and C++ whatever looks cleaner is preferable. First write clear code, then profile it and see if it's intolerably slow.

Comment: clearly hes talking about int a. how can you add 1 to a class

Comment: i'm want to know a++ is fast why so i want the explanation how it's efficient than a = a +1 in efficient memory programming ?

Comment: You can add one to a `char` and a `pointer` if you want to, so sharptooth's point is perfectly valid.

Comment: @user - By overloading the addition operator. Condescension and incorrectness are a terrible combination.

Comment: @user521180: That's easy - I overload `operator+` to accept `int`.

Comment: @sharptooth I'm not trying to be funny but you can also modify the compiler to make ++ take a million intructions in order to work. Say ++ was not overloaded and nothing is changed in anyway...then what's more effecient?

Comment: @user521180: In case of primitive types (like `int` or pointers) there will likely be no difference at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think I would answer in an implementation independent way. The `a++` is easier to read to me because it's just showing me what it does. Whereas for `a = a + 1` I first have to scan all the addition. I prefer to go for the choice that's more foolproof.

The former, `a++`, evaluates to the *prior* value, so you can use it to express things in sometimes surprisingly simpler manners. For instance

```
// copy, until '\0' is hit.
while(*dest++ = *source++) ;
```

Apart from these considerations, I don't think any of them is more efficient, assuming you have to do with basic integer types.

Comment: while(*dest++ = *source++); - I like this statement, as all that are super-concise.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in microprocessor design, but I guess many processors have a INC or DEC instruction. If the data type is int then increment can be done in one instruction. But a = a + 1 requires more, first add and then assignment. So a++ should be faster, obviously assuming that a is not a complex data type.

However a smart compile should do this kind of optimization.

Comment: However, depending on the architecture, you may want the two byte add instruction instead of a one byte inc instruction.  Specifically, loops and jumps are often more efficient when aligned to certain boundaries so using the extra byte for alignment purposes.  But really, this is a compiler issue and we programmers shouldn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

With an optimizing compiler they are identical. The interview question is moot.

Comment: Not if you've overloaded `operator=`, `operator+`, or `operator++` for the type of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no difference between `a++` and `a = a + 1.`

HOWEVER, there is a difference between `++a` and `a = a + 1`

Let's take the first case, `a = a + 1`.

`a = a + 1` will have to take the value of a, add one to it, and then store the result back to a.

`++a` will be a single assembly instruction.

You can notice the difference with these two examples:

**Example 1**

```
int a = 1;
int x = a++; //x will be 1
```

**Example 2**

```
int a = 1;
int x = ++a; //x will be 2
```

BE AWARE! Most compilers optimize this today. If you have a++ somewhere in your code it will MOST likely be optimized to a single assembly instruction.

Comment: There is also a subtle but important difference as to when the value of a changes.

Comment: @Sohnee - Yes, for the ++a and a = a + 1, but not a++ and a = a + 1, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Even more efficient in many cases in ++a. When a is an int or a pointer though it is not going to make any difference.

The rationale of why these increments are more efficient though than `a=a+1` is because the instruction of increment is one instruction whereas the instructions involved in adding 1 to a then assigning it back is something like:

get the address of a
push its contents onto the stack
push 1 to the stack
add them
get the address of a (possibly already stored)
write (pop) from the stack into this address

Comment: C syntax is nothing relevant with assembler insturctions. If expressions have same effect they may be compiled identical. Note, most (especially RISC) CPUs have no arithemic instructions affecting memory locations directly, so both will result 3 instructions: LOAD, ADD, STORE.

Answer (score 0):

Really it all boils down to what your compiler does optimize.

Lets take the optimal case of a is an int. Then normally your compiler will make `a++` and `a=a+1` be exactly the same.

Now what can be pointed out, is that `a = a + 1;` is purely incrementing the value of the fixed amount 1,
whereas `a++` is incrementing the value of 1 of the type of the variable. So if it is an int, float etc you'll get 1->2, 3.4->4.4 in both cases.

But if `a` is a pointer to a array/list etc, you'll be able to change pointer to the next element in the list/array when using `a++`, while `a = a+1` might do something else or not work at all.

---

Long answer short, I'd say `a++` is better:

- your code is clearer and shorter
- your can manipulate a wider range of varaibles types
- and should be more efficient since (I think but I'm not sure) `++` is a basic operator on the same level as `<<` etc.: it modifies directly the variable, while `a = a + 1`, if not optimized by your compiler, will require more operations by adding a with another number.

Comment: means a++ will take less instruction as compared to a = a + 1;

Comment: yep thats what I remember. if you consider without any smart optimization form your compiler) a=a+1 your program has to add bit by bit a (1010...1101)with 1 (000...0001) and put it back into a

Answer (score -1):

```
++a;
a+=1;
a=a+1;
```

Which notation should we use? Why?

We prefer the first version, **++a**, because it more directly expresses the idea of incrementing. It says what we want to do (increment a) rather than how to do it.
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
(add 1 to a and then write the result to a).

In general, a way of saying something in a program is better than another if it more directly expresses an idea.

The result is more concise and easier for a reader to understand. If we wrote a=a+1, a reader could easily wonder whether we really meant to increment by 1.

Maybe we just mistyped **a=b+1**, **a=a+2**, or even **a=a–1**.

With **++a** there are far fewer opportunities for such doubts.

Note: This is a logical argument about readability and correctness, not an  argument about efficiency. Contrary to popular belief. 
Modern compilers tend to generate exactly the same code from **a=a+1** as for **++a** when a is one of the built-in types.

Answer (score -4):

from http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.15 :

> ++i is sometimes faster than, and is never slower than, i++.

Comment: Groundless assertion. In contradiction `y=f(x++)` have lower computation _height_ than `y=f(++x)` (1 tick versus 2 ticks) because f(x) and x=x+1 can be computed in parallel in first but cannot in second.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, though - this was about `a++` versus `a = a + 1`, not `a++` versus `++a`.

Answer (score -9):

a++ is better than a+1 because in the case of floating point numbers a++ increments more efficiently than a=a+1. I.e. a++ increments exactly 1 and no rounding takes place.